# xml soap response parse pdf file oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, soap, oracle-apex

I am consuming a SOAP base service which is returning a pdf file in response, i want to parse response into a blob type. I have below code to consume soap service , however i am getting pdf file but its failed open or download as its invalid file.

```
declare
p_ref_no varchar2(100) := '290313008810';
l_key varchar2(100) := post_shipments_shipper.getKey('LIVE');
l_envelope  CLOB;
l_xml       XMLTYPE;
l_result    varchar2(2000);
l_pdf       clob;
l_pdf_file blob;
pragma autonomous_transaction;
    begin
        l_envelope := '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
         <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sms="http://track.smsaexpress.com/secom/SMSAWebserviceIntl">
            <soapenv:Body>
                <sms:getPDF>
                 <sms:awbNo>'||p_ref_no||'</sms:awbNo>
                 <sms:passKey>'||l_key||'</sms:passKey>                            
              </sms:getPDF>
           </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Envelope>';
      -- Get the XML response from the web service.
      l_xml := APEX_WEB_SERVICE.make_request(
        p_url      => 'http://track.smsaexpress.com/SECOM/SMSAwebServiceIntl.asmx',
        p_action   => 'http://track.smsaexpress.com/secom/SMSAWebserviceIntl/getPDF',
        p_envelope => l_envelope
      );
      -- Display the whole SOAP document returned.
     -- DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('l_xml= ' || l_xml.getClobVal());
    -- RETURN l_xml.getClobVal();  
     
      l_pdf := APEX_WEB_SERVICE.parse_xml_clob(
        p_xml   => l_xml,
        p_xpath => '//getPDFResult',
        p_ns    => 'xmlns="http://track.smsaexpress.com/secom/SMSAWebserviceIntl"'
      );    
              
        l_pdf_file := APEX_WEB_SERVICE.CLOBBASE642BLOB(l_pdf);

        delete from shipment_labels;

        insert into shipment_labels values (l_pdf_file,'abc.pdf','application/pdf',l_pdf);
        commit;          

    end;
```

I am trying to to parse pdf file and inserting into a table with column type blob , however file contents are invalid and unable to open as media.

Comment: Does the service you are accessing really respond with XML-wrapped, Base-64 encoded version of a binary PDF? That seems like an incredibly inefficient method.

Comment: Yes the service output is binary pdf

Comment: can you please suggest some efficient method to save file into a table

Comment: It looks like you're saving both `l_pdf_file` and `l_pdf` into columns. Can you tell us the column types of `shipment_labels` table? Also can you show us the beginning and end of one of the `l_pdf` values, to make sure it is all Base64 with no xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is in your `parse_xml_clob` call. If you look at your l_pdf values which are getting saved in the table, I think they will look like this:

```
<getPDFResult xmlns="http://track.smsaexpress.com/secom/SMSAWebserviceIntl">...your base64Binary...</getPDFResult>
```

But you only want the inside text. Based on [the example in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc.42/e35127/GUID-F52369D1-6E32-4170-97EA-D06B1CF93FA5.htm#AEAPI1940), you want the XPath to return the text node(s) inside the `<getPDFResult>` node, not the node itself.

```
l_pdf := APEX_WEB_SERVICE.parse_xml_clob(
    p_xml   => l_xml,
    p_xpath => '//getPDFResult/text()',
    p_ns    => 'xmlns="http://track.smsaexpress.com/secom/SMSAWebserviceIntl"'
  );
```